# find values with a parent id and update child values with parents values using controller and model using Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have a table called issues where all my new tasks are stored. Both parent and children tasks have custom values that are stored in the custom_values table. I am trying update all the children's custom values in the custom_values table with the parents custom values. I have to get the ID of the parent from the issues, and use that to search the custom_values table to save all the parents custom_values. then search for all the ids of the children with the parent_id in the issues tables. and then update all the children's custom_values, using their issues ID obtained from the issues table. I have an issues controller and a issues model. The copy.id is my parent id. I'm trying to do this from the model after a issue is copied. The code in bold is my attempt.

```
  # Callback for after the creation of an issue by copy
  # * adds a "copied to" relation with the copied issue
  # * copies subtasks from the copied issue
  def after_create_from_copy
    return unless copy? && !@after_create_from_copy_handled

    if (@copied_from.project_id == project_id || Setting.cross_project_issue_relations?) && @copy_options[:link] != false
      if @current_journal
        @copied_from.init_journal(@current_journal.user)
      end
      relation = IssueRelation.new(:issue_from => @copied_from, :issue_to => self, :relation_type => IssueRelation::TYPE_COPIED_TO)
      unless relation.save
        logger.error "Could not create relation while copying ##{@copied_from.id} to ##{id} due to validation errors: #{relation.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}" if logger
      end
    end

    unless @copied_from.leaf? || @copy_options[:subtasks] == false
      copy_options = (@copy_options || {}).merge(:subtasks => false)
      copied_issue_ids = {@copied_from.id => self.id}
      @copied_from.reload.descendants.reorder("#{Issue.table_name}.lft").each do |child|
        # Do not copy self when copying an issue as a descendant of the copied issue
        next if child == self
        # Do not copy subtasks of issues that were not copied
        next unless copied_issue_ids[child.parent_id]
        # Do not copy subtasks that are not visible to avoid potential disclosure of private data
        unless child.visible?
          logger.error "Subtask ##{child.id} was not copied during ##{@copied_from.id} copy because it is not visible to the current user" if logger
          next
        end
        copy = Issue.new.copy_from(child, copy_options)
        if @current_journal
          copy.init_journal(@current_journal.user)
        end
        copy.author = author
        copy.project = project
        copy.parent_issue_id = copied_issue_ids[child.parent_id]
        unless copy.save
          logger.error "Could not copy subtask ##{child.id} while copying ##{@copied_from.id} to ##{id} due to validation errors: #{copy.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}" if logger
          next
        end
        copied_issue_ids[child.id] = copy.id


        **# find custom values for parent id
        # find issue ids for each child.parent.id = copy.id
        # Foreach issue id upate custom values to equal parent custom values. 
        # get name objects from the database 
        # add select as an optimization if desired
        search_parent_custom_field_values = custom_field_values.where(' customized_id = ?', copy.id)
        # this returns array of issue numbers
        search_child_parent_id_issue = issues.where(' parent_id = ?', copy.id)
        #get all cfv where customized_id 
        search_child_parent_id_cfv = custom_field_values.where(' customized_id = ?', search_child_parent_id_issue)
        #for each child issue_id get cfv 
        search_child_parent_id.each do |childIssue|
          # run query to get data from custom_values where customized_id = child issue id
          search_child_parent_id_cfv = custom_field_values.where(' customized_id = ?', childIssue)
          if search_parent_custom_field_values.custom_field_id =  search_child_parent_id_cfv.custom_field_id {
            search_child_parent_id_cfv.each {|values|  
              custom_field_values.update( values.value = search_parent_custom_field_values.value )
            }
          }**

      end
    end
    @after_create_from_copy_handled = true
  end
```

Comment: The code is list above is found in my issues.rb model. and I'm trying to update my custom_values table. Below is the full issues.rb code:

Comment: `code` I found that the inject above will work fine.. I just have to figure out how to gt the first row of values to be injected for all the other custom values

Comment: `code 
# Copies attributes from another issue, arg can be an id or an Issue def copy_from(arg, options={}) issue = arg.is_a?(Issue) ? arg Issue.visible.find(arg) self.custom_field_values = issue.custom_field_values.inject({}) {|h,v| h[v.custom_field_id] = v.value; h} self.status = issue.status self.author = User.current logger.info("modelKandace 
#{self.attributes"}") unless options[:attachments] == false self.attachments = issue.attachments.map do |attachement| attachement.copy(:container => self) end end `

Comment: {def copy_from(arg, options={})
    issue = arg.is_a?(Issue) ? arg : Issue.visible.find(arg)
    self.attributes = issue.attributes.dup.except("id", "root_id", "parent_id", "lft", "rgt", "created_on", "updated_on")
    self.custom_field_values = issue.custom_field_values.inject({}) {|h,v| h[v.custom_field_id] = v.value; h}
    self.status = issue.status
    self.author = User.current}